# How to hide the text in the textbox value?

Tags: php

I have got a problem with my PHP. In my code, it show that the text `<?php if (!empty()) { echo ; } ?>` is show in the value of the textbox when I run the script. I don't want to remove the text in the value, because I need to use them when I open the pop up to input the list of strings from the variable `$email_str` so I can output the list of strings in the textbox.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

include('config.php');

if($_GET['id'] != '')
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];  
    $readDateTime = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
    mysql_query("update tracker set isRead='1', readDateTime='$readDateTime' where id='$id'");
    header('Location: http://robsite.com/phpmailer/examples/blank.jpg');
    exit;
}
else
{


    echo "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
    <title>Send Email</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'  />
    <script src='jquery-1.12.0.js'></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#popup').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var popup = window.open('add_address.php', '_blank', 'toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=100, left=500, width=400, height=400');
                if (popup != null && !popup.closed) {
                var element = popup.document.getElementById('thePopupField');
                var text = $('#theField').val();
                 if(text != ''){
                    var count = (text.match(/,/g) || []).length;
                    popup.my_count = count+1;
                    popup.my_special_setting = text.replace(/,/g, '\n');
                 }
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!---->
    <form action='pr_send.php' method='POST' id='theForm'>
    <table> 
        <!-- <tr>
            <td>From:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='from'></td>
        </tr> -->
        <tr>
            <td><input type='button' name='to' value='' style='height:24px; width:24px; background: url(\"addressbook.png\"); border:none;' id='popup' > To:</td> <!--onClick='Popup()'-->
            <td><input type='text' id='theField' name='to' value='<?php if (!empty($email_str)) { echo $email_str; } ?>' style='height:15px; width:650px'>&nbsp;(<span id='noOfEmails'>0</span>)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Subject:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='subject' style='height:15px; width:650px'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Message:</td>
            <td><textarea name='message' cols='90' rows='20'></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' align='left'>
               <input type='submit' name='send' value='' style='height:35px; width:100px; background: url(\"send.png\"); border:none'>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
<!--<script type='text/javascript'>
var popup = null;
function Popup() 
{
  window.open('add_address.php', '_blank', 'toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=100, left=500, width=400, height=400');
}
function closePopUp() 
{
  if (popup) 
  {
    popup.close();
  }
}

</script>-->

</html>";
}

  if (!empty($_POST['message'])) 
  {
    $emails = explode("\n", $_POST['message']); // explode textarea on a line break into an array
    $email_str = implode(", ", $emails); // take each of the emails and implode together with the ,

    echo '<script> closePopUp(); </script>'; //call javascript function
  }  
?>
```

When I ran the code in HTML, it works fine as the text did not show in the textbox.

How I can hide the text in the value when I run the html code in PHP?

Comment: you could use input type hidden

Comment: @rtfm I am sorry but I cant use the input type hidden because I am using the text input as I want to see the textbox when I run the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have your PHP tag inside the string that you are printing with your `echo`. So, with the proposed fix, you are executing the PHP code and concatening it to the HTML string you want to print.

```
<?php

include('config.php');

if($_GET['id'] != '')
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];  
    $readDateTime = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
    mysql_query("update tracker set isRead='1', readDateTime='$readDateTime' where id='$id'");
    header('Location: http://robsite.com/phpmailer/examples/blank.jpg');
    exit;
}
else
{

    $email = !empty($email_str) ? $email_str : "";
    $html = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
    <title>Send Email</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'  />
    <script src='jquery-1.12.0.js'></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#popup').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var popup = window.open('add_address.php', '_blank', 'toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=100, left=500, width=400, height=400');
                if (popup != null && !popup.closed) {
                var element = popup.document.getElementById('thePopupField');
                var text = $('#theField').val();
                 if(text != ''){
                    var count = (text.match(/,/g) || []).length;
                    popup.my_count = count+1;
                    popup.my_special_setting = text.replace(/,/g, '\n');
                 }
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!---->
    <form action='pr_send.php' method='POST' id='theForm'>
    <table> 
        <!-- <tr>
            <td>From:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='from'></td>
        </tr> -->
        <tr>
            <td><input type='button' name='to' value='' style='height:24px; width:24px; background: url(\"addressbook.png\"); border:none;' id='popup' > To:</td> <!--onClick='Popup()'-->
            <td><input type='text' id='theField' name='to' value='".$email."' style='height:15px; width:650px'>&nbsp;(<span id='noOfEmails'>0</span>)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Subject:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='subject' style='height:15px; width:650px'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Message:</td>
            <td><textarea name='message' cols='90' rows='20'></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' align='left'>
               <input type='submit' name='send' value='' style='height:35px; width:100px; background: url(\"send.png\"); border:none'>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
<!--<script type='text/javascript'>
var popup = null;
function Popup() 
{
  window.open('add_address.php', '_blank', 'toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=100, left=500, width=400, height=400');
}
function closePopUp() 
{
  if (popup) 
  {
    popup.close();
  }
}

</script>-->

</html>";

echo $html;
}

  if (!empty($_POST['message'])) 
  {
    $emails = explode("\n", $_POST['message']); // explode textarea on a line break into an array
    $email_str = implode(", ", $emails); // take each of the emails and implode together with the ,

    echo '<script> closePopUp(); </script>'; //call javascript function
  }  
?>
```

Comment: thank you very much for this, but there is an error: `unexpected T_IF`. Do you have any idea why I am getting this?

Comment: Because you can't run an if-statement inside an echo. Do this: `value="'.(!empty($email_str) ? $email_str : '').'"` Basically, what this does is using a ternary operator for the if-statement, and if the variable is empty, it will just have an empty value.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie thank you but i am getting this in the textbox now`.(!empty() ?  : ` any idea??

Comment: oops, @junkfoodjunkie is right. To solve that you can store the string on a variable, replace the word `echo` by `$html = ` then after all long html string, place this: `echo $html;`

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres I try to use use it will show `echo` in the textbox. Any idea?

Comment: @RobertJones Copy the code that I added to my answer and replace yours with it. It should be working.

Answer (score 0):

You build a page of HTML as a PHP string, but you are trying to include PHP code within that PHP string.

PHP runs on the server side, not on the client.  If you send PHP code as text to the client it will be ignored.

Also, you are not giving $email_str a value until after you've already used it.

Move the code to set $email_str to before you use it, and also give it a default value of "" if the POST data is not there.

Then for your echo, split it into 3 parts:

- first part of page string up to value='
- echo $email_str  (which you now set to "" if no POST)
- rest of page

code

```
 echo "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3    ...  <input type='text' id='theField' name='to' value='";
 echo $email_str
 echo "' style='height:15px; width:65  ... </html>";
```

Comment: thank you for your advice. Im not really sure what do you expect me to do. Can you show me an example as I want to see what I need to do in a proper way? thanks!

Comment: edited, see added code.  or like @junkfoodjunkie says you can actually just include $email_str in the giant string and let PHP substitute the value (that is, get rid of the <?php  > bits).  That's fine if you give $email_str a default of ""